# Why is my iOS app's binary invalid when uploading a new version?

Tags: ios, binary, itunes

Im adding a version of a app to iTunes that already published. now I did some big fix and
upload the binary to the itunes. but after uploading it says invalid binary with a red dot. even I validated it from the xCode. what is the reason for this? and how I can solve this

Answer (score 0):

Could be a lot of reasons. The common one these days is the UDID deprecation. 
Are you doing anything related to UDID in your app? Just to make sure, go to your project library within the terminal and type:

```
$ find . | grep -v .svn  | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier
```

If you're getting a result, that's your problem.
Also check your email, there's a mail from apple assigned to that Invalid Binary notice with more details.

Comment: this is my company profile,, so I cannot chk the mail,,, is there any way to know about from the apple?

Comment: Not that I know of, I've edited my answer with more information, run the command line there, maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Are you supporting for iphone 5?

Comment: my app is supporting iPhone 5

Comment: Means have you added images for iphone 5 i.e. application has support for iphone 5 ?

Comment: I have added default image for iphone 5 and normal. and also I have seperate xib set for the iPhone 5

Comment: Have you executed the command above in the terminal inside your project folder?

Comment: @iDa Then only way is that check out the mail. After that only you can find out the issue as said by user1779765.

Comment: I gave this command as it is inside my project folder,,, It says command not found

Comment: Are you on a mac? That's a simple find command on the terminal

Comment: Write it without the $ at the beginning.

Comment: Write it without the $ at the beginning like this `find . | grep -v .svn  | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31237/discussion-between-idia-and-sha)

Answer (score 0):

Best solution you send Email to Developer support Team, They are Help you immediately. Because lot of reasons the Build is Invalid Binary. I am faced this problem, I contact Apple team they give solution.

Thanks.